# Python test method for additional method call

Tags: python-3.x, testing, pytest

I have a situation and i could not find anything online that would help.
my understanding is that python testing is rigorous to ensure that if someone changes a method, the test would fail and alert the developers to go rectify the difference.

I have a method that calls 4 other methods from other classes. Patching made it real easy for me to determine if a method has been called. However, let's say someone in my team decides to add a 5th method, the test will still pass. Assuming that no other method calls should be allowed inside, is there a way to test in python to make sure no other calls are made? Refer to example.py below:

example.py:

```
def example():
    classA.method1()
    classB.method2()
    classC.method3()
    classD.method4()
    classE.method5()  # we do not want this method in here, test should fail if it detects a 5th or more method.
```

Is there anyway to cause the test case to fail if any additional methods are added?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily test (with `mock` or doing the mocking manually)  that `example()` does not **specifically** calls `classE.method5`, but that's about all you can expect - it won't work (unless explicitely tested too)  for ie `classF.method6()`.  Such a test would require either parsing the `example` function's source code or analysing it's bytecode representation.

This being said:

> my understanding is that python testing is rigorous to ensure that if someone changes a method, the test would fail

I'm afraid your understanding is a bit off - it's not about "changing the method", it's about "unexpectedly changing behaviour". IOW you should first test for behaviour (black box testing), not for implementation (white box testing).  Now the distinction between "implementation" and "behaviour" can be a bit blurry depending on the context (you can consider that "calling X.y()" is part of the expected behaviour and it sometimes makes sense indeed), but the distinction is still important.

wrt/ your current use case (and without more context - ie why shouldn't the function call anything else ?), I'd personnaly wouldn't bother trying be that defensive and I'd just clearly document this requirement as a comment in the `example()` function itself so anyone editing this code immediatly knows what he should not do.